# Too many open files error! Can't open Jenkins after installing many plugins

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, hudson

I searched the previous threads but did not solve my problems. I am using Ubuntu.

The Problem is this:

Error java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /var/lib/jenkins/config.xml: 
Too many open files at

sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:103) at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:114) at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:119) at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:226) at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:372) at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:418) at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:395) at java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:163) at hudson.XmlFile.unmarshal(XmlFile.java:158) at jenkins.model.Jenkins.loadConfig(Jenkins.java:3078) at jenkins.model.Jenkins.access$1200(Jenkins.java:307) at jenkins.model.Jenkins$16.run(Jenkins.java:3096) at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169) at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:282) at jenkins.model.Jenkins$7.runTask(Jenkins.java:1090) at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:210) at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1153) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:785)

Caused: org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.execute(Reactor.java:269) at jenkins.InitReactorRunner.run(InitReactorRunner.java:47) at jenkins.model.Jenkins.executeReactor(Jenkins.java:1124) at jenkins.model.Jenkins.(Jenkins.java:929) at hudson.model.Hudson.(Hudson.java:86) at hudson.model.Hudson.(Hudson.java:82) at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:235)

Caused: hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:252)

Comment: I provided two solutions below. Please check it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you install Jenkins, it creates a default **jenkins** user. Please note your every action that you performed on Jenkins is associated with "Jenkins" user. In Ubuntu (you told your OS is Ubuntu), there is open files limit. You can know, the open files limit using `ulimit -n` from the user-shell. For example, if you want to know "`ulimit -n`" for "jenkins" user, you do: Change shell to "jenkins" user doing "`su - jenkins`" and then `ulimit -n`. The default value is 1024. You can increase this value to 4096 or more doing: `ulimit -n 4096`.

**Alternatively**, you can create a new ulimit record in `/etc/security/limits.conf` file as below.

```
jenkins      soft   nofile  4096
jenkins      hard   nofile  8192
```

**Explanation** (you can read /etc/security/limits.conf file for better understanding)

*jenkins* -- a user/group name

*soft/ hard* -- type of link. 
**Note**: soft link can be from 0 to hardlink.

*nofile* -- number of open files
And the  is value.